# Powershell regex group replacing

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I want to replace some text in every script file in folder, and I'm trying to use this PS code:

```
$pattern = '(FROM [a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,100})(?<replacement_place>[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,7})'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Scripts' -Recurse -Include *.sql | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_.fullname) -replace $pattern, 'replace text' | Set-Content $_.fullname }
```

But I have no idea how to keep first part of expression, and just replace the second one. Any idea how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Not sure that provided *regex* for tables names is correct, but anyway you could replace with captures using variables `$1`, `$2` and so on, and following [syntax](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions): `'Doe, John' -ireplace '(\w+), (\w+)', '$2 $1'`

Note that the replacement pattern either needs to be in single quotes (`''`) or have the `$` signs of the replacement group specifiers escaped (`` "`$2 `$1" ``).

```
# may better replace with     $pattern = '(FROM) (?<replacement_place>[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,7})'
$pattern = '(FROM [a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,100})(?<replacement_place>[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,7})'

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Scripts' -Recurse -Include *.sql | % `
{
   (Get-Content $_.fullname) | % `
     { $_-replace $pattern, '$1 replace text' } | 
     Set-Content $_.fullname -Force
}
```

If you need to reference *other* variables in your replacement expression (as you may), you can use a double-quoted string and escape the capture dollars with a backtick

```
     { $_-replace $pattern, "`$1 replacement text with $somePoshVariable" } |
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I need. Regex correctness doesnt matter in that case, I just need to learn a way.

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful in the past.  I am having trouble now referencing another variable where there is no space between the first capture and the variable, like this: `Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $pattern, "\`$1$version\`$3"}`.  I am wanting output of `<VersionPrefix>1.1.35</VersionPrefix>` but am getting `$11.1.35</VersionPrefix>`, obviously the parser is not recognising I want a capture there.  Is there a way around this?  If I put a space between the capture and the variable it works, but then I have an extra space which breaks later.

Comment: @Peter did you ever find a fix for this? Having the exact same problem

Comment: @user3700562 - looks like I did a bit of a work-around like this: `Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $pattern, "\`$1\`>$version\`$3"}` - can't remember the details!

Comment: @user3700562 surround the # in curly braces like `${1}$version` in your case

Comment: It appears curly braces are the correct syntax for named capture groups as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#Named