# How to replace first and last part of each line with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I would like to use PowerShell to modify a text file.

I would like to **-replace**:

- `[REPLACE` at the beginning of each line with `ENJOY`
- `LINE]` at the end of each line with `LIFE`
- only if the line starts with `[REPLACE` and ends with `LINE]`

**What would be the regex expression used in -replace to match this request ?**

*Example - File Input*

```
[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]
[DO_NOT_REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE_PLEASE]
[REPLACE_VERY_MUCH_IN_THIS_LINE]
Do not replace in this line[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]
```

*Example - File Output*

```
ENJOY_IN_THIS_LIFE
[DO_NOT_REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE_PLEASE]
ENJOY_VERY_MUCH_IN_THIS_LIFE
Do not replace in this line[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]
```

As you can see, in this example, only 2nd and 4th lines have changed...

I came up with this for matching the string: `-match "^\[REPLACE.*LINE\]$"` but I don't know how to use `-replace` to correctly replace...

Comment: post regex you're currently using

Comment: @stetoc I just added what I'm using for -match `-match "^\[REPLACE.*LINE\]$"` but I don't know how to transform this to `-replace` to be able to replace only the first and last part and leave the middle as it is...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use "^" will validate start of line and "$" will handle end of line. I have written a code in Java but you can use this regex.

```
String input="[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]"
Pattern Pat=Pattern.compile(("^(\\[REPLACE)(.)*(LINE\\])$"));
Matcher Mat=Pat.matcher();
if(Mat.find())
{
    input=input.replace("[REPLACE","Enjoy").replace("LINE]","Life")
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you break this in 2 steps: 1.check if the string matches the pattern 2. replace what needs to be replaced.

Comment: Yes I tried to solve this problem by using this solution.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Simply just try string replace functions.

as in Java

```
String inputValue="[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]".replaceAll("[REPLACE","Enjoy").replaceAll("LINE]","Life");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call replace 2 times, one for each string that you want to replace, considering that you use a loop for access each line you must do something like this:

```
$ResultText = $line.replace("[REPLACE","ENJOY").replace("LINE]","LIFE")
```

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the question, I didn't consider that you can have "[REPLACE" in the middle of the text. Try the following:

```
'[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE][REPLACE' -replace '^\[REPLACE(.*?)', 'ENJOY$1'
```

And then:

```
'[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE][REPLACE_LINE]' -replace '(.+?)LINE\]$', '$1LIFE'
```

As you can see the first one only replace the first "[REPLACE" and the 2nd one replace only the first "LINE]".

Comment: This is not correct. This will replace every `[REPLACE` and `LINE]` which is not what I want to do. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: @JasminStarvors Sorry, I have edited my answer, take a look if it is what you need. Regards

Answer (score 0):

try somthing like this :

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt" |%{

    if ($_ -like 'ENJOY*LIFE')
    {
      "[REPLACE{0}LINE]" -f $_.Substring(5, $_.Length -9)
    }
    else
    {
        $_
    }


} | Set-Content "c:\temp\result.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group placeholders (e.g. `$1`), see e.g.: [Powershell regex group replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11794412/1701026)

```
# $a = Get-Content .\Input.txt
$a = "[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]",
     "[DO_NOT_REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE_PLEASE]",
     "[REPLACE_VERY_MUCH_IN_THIS_LINE]",
     "Do not replace in this line[REPLACE_IN_THIS_LINE]"
```

```
$a -Replace '^\[REPLACE(.*)LINE\]$', 'ENJOY$1LIFE'
```

Answer (score 0):

They are all very complicated and found this solution for me, to use a regex with the multiline flag to iterate over each line:

```
powershell -Command "$fileContent = Get-Content -Raw '<your input path>';$fileContent=$fileContent.replace('^\[REPLACE(.*)LINE\\]$', 'ENJOY$1LIFE');Set-Content '<output-path>' -Value $fileContent"
```