# Why is powershell -replace operator not properly including all characters captured in the capture group?

Tags: powershell

### Edit:

After reviewing this question again, I've added a second example that I hope will highlight where my confusion became amplified, namely there was one capture group accessed by its index (1), and the value I expected from the `$filecontent` was coincidentally also a 1.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794412/powershell-regex-group-replacing) indicates that a back tick can be used to address capture groups in a double quoted string when referencing other variables.

> If you need to reference other variables in your replacement expression (as you may), you can use a double-quoted string and escape the capture dollars with a backtick

However, I'm seeing some interesting behavior that I can't explain.

```
$VersionReplacementRegex = "(\d+\.)\d+" #capture first digit + dot b/c I want to keep it
$BuildVersionValidationRegex = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
    
$VersionData = [regex]::matches("some-18.11.8",$BuildVersionValidationRegex)
$NewVersion = $VersionData[0] #matches 18.11.8

$filecontent = "stuff 1.0.0.0 other stuff" #Get-Content($file)
```

replacing text in `$filecontent` using the capture group as specified in the linked question gives an incomplete result...

```
$filecontent -replace $VersionReplacementRegex, "`$1$NewVersion" | Write-Host
```

returns: `118.11.8`
expected: `1.18.11.8`

But adding a space between the `$1` and `$NewVersion` gives a different yet equally unhelpful result..

```
$filecontent -replace $VersionReplacementRegex, "`$1 $NewVersion" | Write-Host
```

returns: `1. 18.11.8`
The captured dot appears here, but so does the undesirable space.

With this example, the results are somewhat similar, but it seems that the capture group is getting the wrong value all together.

```
$NewVersion = 18.11.8
$filecontent = "stuff 5.0.0.0 other stuff"
$filecontent -replace "(\d+\.)\d+", "`$1$NewVersion" | Write-Host

# returns: 118.11.8
# expected: 5.18.11.8
```

Adding the space in the replacement string returns: `5. 18.11.8`

So, what am I missing, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Judging from past experience, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), who provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question, won't be back to post an answer.</sup>

**tl;dr**

If you use **`-replace` with a replacement operand that references capture groups *and* *PowerShell* variables, use syntax such as `` "`${<ndx>}${<PsVar>}" ``**, where `<ndx>` is the index of your capture group, and `<PsVar>` is the name of your PowerShell variable; note the `` ` `` before the first `$`:

```
PS> $var = '2'; 'foo' -replace '(f)', "[`${1}$var]"
[f2]oo # OK, -replace saw '${1}2'
```

If you neglect to use `{...}` to disambiguate the capture-group index, the replacement malfunctions, because the interpolated string value then effectively references a different index:
`-replace` then sees `[$12]`, which, due to referring to a nonexistent capture group with index `12`, is left as-is:

```
PS> $var = '2'; 'foo' -replace '(f)', "[`$1$var]"
[$12]oo # !! -replace saw '$12', i.e., a nonexistent group with index 12
```

---

**It is tricky to mix PowerShell's *string expansion* (interpolation) with the syntax of the 
`-replace` operator**, because it is **easy to get confused**:

- In *double-quoted* (`"..."`) strings, it is PowerShell's generic *string expansion* (string interpolation) feature that interprets `$` chars *first*, where a `$` prefix refers to (PowerShell) *variables* and, inside `$(...)`, entire *statements*.
- Whatever string is the *result* of that expansion is *then* interpreted by the `-replace` operator, where `$`-prefixed tokens refer to *results of the regex-matching operation*, as summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).
- Note that these layers of `$` interpretation are entire unrelated and the fact that both use sigil `$` is incidental.

Therefore:

- **If your replacement operand *doesn't* need string expansion**, i.e., if there's no need to reference PowerShell *variables* or *expressions*, be sure to **use a *single-quoted* string (`'...'`)**, so that PowerShell's string expansion doesn't come into play:

  ```
   PS> 'foo' -replace '(f)', '[$1]'
   [f]oo  # OK - if you had used "[$1]" instead, the output would be '[]oo',
          # because $1 is then interpreted as a *PowerShell variable*.
  ```
- **If you *do* need to involve string expansion**:

  - **Prefix `$` chars.** that should be passed through to `-replace` **with `` ` ``**

    - `` ` `` (the backtick) is PowerShell's general escape character, and in `"..."` strings it is used to indicate that the next character is to be taken *literally*; placed before a `$`, it suppresses string interpolation for that token; e.g., `` "I'm `$HOME" `` yields literal `I'm $HOME`, i.e., the variable reference was *not* expanded.
  - To **disambiguate references to *capture groups***, e.g., `$1`, **enclose them in `{...}`** - e.g., `${1}`

    - Note that you may also need to use `{...}` to disambiguate *PowerShell* variable names; e.g. `"$HOME1"` must be `"${HOME}1"` in order to reference variable `$HOME` successfully.
    - Also, it is not just about capture-group *indices*; ambiguity can also arise with *named* capture groups; **in `"..."`-based replacement operands, always using `{...}` around capture-group indices / names (and PS variables) is a good habit to form.**
  - If in doubt, output the replacement operand by itself in order to inspect what `-replace` will ultimately see.

    - In the example above, outputting `` "[`$1$var]" `` by itself, which applies the string-interpolation step, would have made the problem more obvious: `[$12]`

To illustrate the latter point:

```
PS> $var = '2'; 'foo' -replace '(f)', "[`$1$var]"
[$12]oo  # !! $1 wasn't recognizes as the 1st capture group.
```

The problem was that `-replace`, after string expansion, saw `[$12]` as the replacement operand, and since there was no capture group with index `12`, it was left as-is.

Enclosing the capture-group number in `{...}` solves the problem:

```
PS> $var = '2'; 'foo' -replace '(f)', "[`${1}$var]"
[f2]oo  # OK
```

Comment: Re first comment: correct, @JoshGust. And, yes, `$` inside `'...'` is only special in the context of `-replace` (behind the scenes, that mini-language is a feature of `[regex]::Replace()`, as summarized in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375). It is coincidental - and unfortunate - that both PowerShell's string interpolation and the .NET regex type's replacement functionality use `$` as the sigil for placeholders / variables.

Comment: Re second comment: True. Let me add: `\`` (backtick) is PowerShell's general escape character; inside `"..."` you can use it to indicate that the following char. is to be taken literally, which in the case of `\`$` suppresses string interpolation and ensures that the `$` is passed through to the `-replace` operator.

Comment: @JoshGust: I've adde a tl;dr section - see if that helps. What may also help is if you made the question clearer, using similarly focused examples.

Comment: @JoshGust: P.S.: it's not just about _numeric_ trailing and leading characters - ambiguity can also arise with _named_ capture groups. As a debugging tip: output the replacement operand by itself to see how it string-expands, which then tells you whether `-replace` sees the operand as intended. I've added this information to the answer too.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use the `\`$<n>` syntax for capture groups and leave the variable syntax as-is

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, no, in this case you need _both_ `\`` _and_ `{...}` in the capture-group reference - look at the last two sample commands in the answer.

Comment: got it. It worked for my very basic case.