# Use variables in string replace - Windows powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

I have a requirement where my string is of format as below:

```
<?define BuildNumber = "8314" ?>
```

I am using below powershell script in TFS 2017 build template to replace the build number value:

```
$content = Get-Content -path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Install\Common\Constants.wxi"
$num  = $(Build.BuildId)
$content -Replace '(BuildNumber\s*=\s*")\d*("\s*)', "`$1 $num `$2" |  Out-File $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Install\Common\Constants.wxi
```

This gives output  like `<?define BuildNumber = " 27994 " ?>` which is incorrect as I do not want spaces in the value.
When I tried using below code, it does not work.

```
$content -Replace '(BuildNumber\s*=\s*")\d*("\s*)', "`$1$num`$2" |  Out-File  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Install\Common\Constants.wxi
```

Output : `<?define $27994 ?>`

I tried all combinations but cannot get the quotations to work correctly. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is powershell -replace operator not properly including all characters captured in the capture group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215162/why-is-powershell-replace-operator-not-properly-including-all-characters-captur)

Comment: `-Replace '(?<=BuildNumber\s*=\s*")\d*(?="\s*)', $num`

Comment: @Olaf This is a solution. I was actually not able to understand why it was not working in the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly braces to "escape" group number

```
$content -Replace '(BuildNumber\s*=\s*")\d*("\s*)', "`${1}$num`$2" | Out-File $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Install\Common\Constants.wxi
```

A little clarification about why the original code doesn't work: after $num variable has been resolved the replace string became **$127994$2**. That means that the -replace operator is trying to find group **$127994** which obviously does not exist. When we add curly braces it becomes **${1}27994$2** which is completely legit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Worked like magic. I am a little new to powershell scripting.

Comment: @Mustafa I've added a clarification about why your code doesn't worked as expected.